# What hardware do I need for 3 monitors on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I currently have...

- Motherboard:
  http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131646
- Video card: GeForce GTX 460 -
  http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814261075

I really want to have 3 monitors on Windows 7. I would like to either get a video card cheap to use for desktop display and leave my GTX 460 as my primary, or replace this card with a significant upgrade which will allow me to run 3 displays.

Is it important that I get a specific video card?

Comment: Some information on what you have looked at so far would be great, as google has more than a few hits... https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=triple+monitor+graphics+card&oq=triple+monitor+graphics+card&gs_l=hp.12..0l2j0i22i30l2.3106.3681.1.4286.3.2.0.1.1.0.160.255.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.jOwD2pjJFSI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aWM&fp=ee928f97580b9630&biw=1280&bih=831 
Eyefinity cards are abundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have a card plugged into your second PCIe x16 slot (the white one) on your motherboard, there is no need to get an expensive card that can run *all* three displays. Simply purchase another graphics card and plug it in to drive the other two displays. Windows will allow you to extend your desktop to any displays plugged into either card.

Unless you want to stretch a game across all three monitors, there is no need for Nvidia Surround or AMD Eyefinity.

Since you already have a Nvidia card, I recommend not purchasing an AMD card so you do not have to have both Nvidia and AMD drivers installed. A Nvidia GT 610 will likely be the cheapest card you will be able to find to stick next to your 460.

Answer (score -1):

[AMD-EYEFINITY](http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/TECHNOLOGIES/AMD-EYEFINITY-TECHNOLOGY/FOR-CONSUMERS/Pages/what-is-eyefinity.aspx)

[image: AMD EYEFINITY]

[AMD EYEFINITY Configuration Tools](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/set-up.aspx)

## NVidia SLI Configuration wizard:

[SLI Multi-Monitor Configuration Tool](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/system-requirements)

GeForce GTX 460 - 2 monitor maximum.

```
GeForce GTX 460 2-way SLI Multi-monitor> Maximum Resolution: 2560x1600 per display

Maximum Displays: 2

Special Instructions:
 Displays can be connected anywhere.
 Orientation can be defined per display.
```

or

```
GeForce GTX 460 3-way SLI Multi-monitor> Maximum Resolution: 2560x1600 per display

Maximum Displays: 2

Special Instructions:
 Displays can be connected anywhere.
 Orientation can be defined per display.
```

AMD Lightning Bolt, as variant.

Comment: I do not think @Webnet is looking for a multi-monitor surround setup. An AMD card that supports Eyefinity card or a NVidia card that supports 3+ displays is not required, nor is Crossfire or SLI. He just needs a second graphics card to drive more monitors.